# Pinning user space buffer for DMA from Linux kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel, dma, pci-e, pinning

I'm writing driver for devices that produce around 1GB of data per second. Because of that I decided to map user buffer allocated by application directly for DMA instead of copying through intermediate kernel buffer.

The code works, more or less. But during long-run stress testing I see kernel oops with "bad page state" initiated by unrelated applications (for instance `updatedb`), probably when kernel wants to swap some pages:

```
[21743.515404] BUG: Bad page state in process PmStabilityTest  pfn:357518
[21743.521992] page:ffffdf844d5d4600 count:19792158 mapcount:0 mapping:          (null) index:0x12b011e012d0132
[21743.531829] flags: 0x119012c01220124(referenced|lru|slab|reclaim|uncached|idle)
[21743.539138] raw: 0119012c01220124 0000000000000000 012b011e012d0132 012e011e011e0111
[21743.546899] raw: 0000000000000000 012101300131011c 0000000000000000 012101240123012b
[21743.554638] page dumped because: page still charged to cgroup
[21743.560383] page->mem_cgroup:012101240123012b
[21743.564745] bad because of flags: 0x120(lru|slab)
[21743.569555] BUG: Bad page state in process PmStabilityTest  pfn:357519
[21743.576098] page:ffffdf844d5d4640 count:18219302 mapcount:18940179 mapping:          (null) index:0x0
[21743.585318] flags: 0x0()
[21743.587859] raw: 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0116012601210112
[21743.595599] raw: 0000000000000000 011301310127012f 0000000000000000 012f011d010d011a
[21743.603336] page dumped because: page still charged to cgroup
[21743.609108] page->mem_cgroup:012f011d010d011a
...
Entering kdb (current=0xffff8948189b2d00, pid 6387) on processor 6 Oops: (null)
due to oops @ 0xffffffff9c87f469
CPU: 6 PID: 6387 Comm: updatedb.mlocat Tainted: G    B      OE   4.10.0-42-generic #46~16.04.1-Ubuntu
...
```

---

Details:

The user buffer consists of frames and neither the buffer not the frames are page-aligned. The frames in buffer are used in circular manner for "infinite" live data transfers. For each frame I get memory pages via `get_user_pages_fast`, then convert it to scatter-gatter table with `sg_alloc_table_from_pages` and finally map for DMA using `dma_map_sg`.

I rely on `sg_alloc_table_from_pages` to bind consecutive pages into one DMA descriptor to reduce size of S/G table sent to device. Devices are custom built and utilize FPGA. I took inspiration from many drivers doing similar mapping, especially video drivers i915 and radeon, but no one has all the stuff on one place so I might overlook something.

Related functions (`pin_user_buffer` and `unpin_user_buffer` are called upon separate IOCTLs):

```
static int pin_user_frame(struct my_dev *cam, struct udma_frame *frame)
{
        const unsigned long bytes = cam->acq_frame_bytes;
        const unsigned long first =
                ( frame->uaddr              &  PAGE_MASK) >> PAGE_SHIFT;
        const unsigned long last =
                ((frame->uaddr + bytes - 1) &  PAGE_MASK) >> PAGE_SHIFT;
        const unsigned long offset =
                  frame->uaddr              & ~PAGE_MASK;
        int nr_pages = last - first + 1;
        int err;
        int n;
        struct page **pages;
        struct sg_table *sgt;

        if (frame->uaddr + bytes < frame->uaddr) {
                pr_err("%s: attempted user buffer overflow!\n", __func__);
                return -EINVAL;
        }

        if (bytes == 0) {
                pr_err("%s: user buffer has zero bytes\n", __func__);
                return -EINVAL;
        }

        pages = kcalloc(nr_pages, sizeof(*pages), GFP_KERNEL | __GFP_ZERO);
        if (!pages) {
                pr_err("%s: can't allocate udma_frame.pages\n", __func__);
                return -ENOMEM;
        }

        sgt = kzalloc(sizeof(*sgt), GFP_KERNEL);
        if (!sgt) {
                pr_err("%s: can't allocate udma_frame.sgt\n", __func__);
                err = -ENOMEM;
                goto err_alloc_sgt;
        }

        /* (rw == READ) means read from device, write into memory area */
        err = get_user_pages_fast(frame->uaddr, nr_pages, READ == READ, pages);
        if (err < nr_pages) {
                nr_pages = err;
                if (err > 0) {
                        pr_err("%s: can't pin all %d user pages, got %d\n",
                               __func__, nr_pages, err);
                        err = -EFAULT;
                } else {
                        pr_err("%s: can't pin user pages\n", __func__);
                }
                goto err_get_pages;
        }

        for (n = 0; n < nr_pages; ++n)
                flush_dcache_page(pages[n]); //<--- Is this needed?

        err = sg_alloc_table_from_pages(sgt, pages, nr_pages, offset, bytes,
                                        GFP_KERNEL);
        if (err) {
                pr_err("%s: can't build sg_table for %d pages\n",
                       __func__, nr_pages);
                goto err_alloc_sgt2;
        }

        if (!dma_map_sg(&cam->pci_dev->dev, sgt->sgl, sgt->nents, DMA_FROM_DEVICE)) {
                pr_err("%s: can't map %u sg_table entries for DMA\n",
                       __func__, sgt->nents);
                err = -ENOMEM;
                goto err_dma_map;
        }

        frame->pages = pages;
        frame->nr_pages = nr_pages;
        frame->sgt = sgt;

        return 0;

err_dma_map:
        sg_free_table(sgt);

err_alloc_sgt2:
err_get_pages:
        for (n = 0; n < nr_pages; ++n)
                put_page(pages[n]);
        kfree(sgt);

err_alloc_sgt:
        kfree(pages);

        return err;
}

static void unpin_user_frame(struct my_dev *cam, struct udma_frame *frame)
{
        int n;

        dma_unmap_sg(&cam->pci_dev->dev, frame->sgt->sgl, frame->sgt->nents,
                     DMA_FROM_DEVICE);

        sg_free_table(frame->sgt);
        kfree(frame->sgt);
        frame->sgt = NULL;

        for (n = 0; n < frame->nr_pages; ++n) {
                struct page *page = frame->pages[n];
                set_page_dirty_lock(page);
                mark_page_accessed(page); //<--- Without this the Oops are more frequent
                put_page(page);
        }
        kfree(frame->pages);
        frame->pages = NULL;

        frame->nr_pages = 0;
}

static void unpin_user_buffer(struct my_dev *cam)
{
        if (cam->udma_frames) {
                int n;
                for (n = 0; n < cam->udma_frame_count; ++n)
                        unpin_user_frame(cam, &cam->udma_frames[n]);
                kfree(cam->udma_frames);
                cam->udma_frames = NULL;
        }
        cam->udma_frame_count = 0;
        cam->udma_buffer_bytes = 0;
        cam->udma_buffer = NULL;
        cam->udma_desc_count = 0;
}

static int pin_user_buffer(struct my_dev *cam)
{
        int err;
        int n;
        const u32 acq_frame_count = cam->acq_buffer_bytes / cam->acq_frame_bytes;
        struct udma_frame *udma_frames;
        u32 udma_desc_count = 0;

        if (!cam->acq_buffer) {
                pr_err("%s: user buffer is NULL!\n", __func__);
                return -EFAULT;
        }

        if (cam->udma_buffer == cam->acq_buffer
            && cam->udma_buffer_bytes == cam->acq_buffer_bytes
            && cam->udma_frame_count == acq_frame_count)
                return 0;

        if (cam->udma_buffer)
                unpin_user_buffer(cam);

        udma_frames = kcalloc(acq_frame_count, sizeof(*udma_frames),
                              GFP_KERNEL | __GFP_ZERO);
        if (!udma_frames) {
                pr_err("%s: can't allocate udma_frame array for %u frames\n",
                       __func__, acq_frame_count);
                return -ENOMEM;
        }

        for (n = 0; n < acq_frame_count; ++n) {
                struct udma_frame *frame = &udma_frames[n];
                frame->uaddr =
                        (unsigned long)(cam->acq_buffer + n * cam->acq_frame_bytes);
                err = pin_user_frame(cam, frame);
                if (err) {
                        pr_err("%s: can't pin frame %d (out of %u)\n",
                               __func__, n + 1, acq_frame_count);
                        for (--n; n >= 0; --n)
                                unpin_user_frame(cam, frame);
                        kfree(udma_frames);
                        return err;
                }
                udma_desc_count += frame->sgt->nents; /* Cannot overflow */
        }
        pr_debug("%s: total udma_desc_count=%u\n", __func__, udma_desc_count);

        cam->udma_buffer = cam->acq_buffer;
        cam->udma_buffer_bytes = cam->acq_buffer_bytes;
        cam->udma_frame_count = acq_frame_count;
        cam->udma_frames = udma_frames;
        cam->udma_desc_count = udma_desc_count;

        return 0;
}
```

Related structures:

```
struct udma_frame {
        unsigned long   uaddr;      /* User address of the frame */
        int             nr_pages;   /* Nr. of pages covering the frame */
        struct page     **pages;    /* Actual pages covering the frame */
        struct sg_table *sgt;       /* S/G table describing the frame */
};

struct my_dev {
        ...
        u8 __user   *acq_buffer;   /* User-space buffer received via IOCTL */
        ...
        u8 __user   *udma_buffer;       /* User-space buffer for image */
        u32         udma_buffer_bytes;  /* Total image size in bytes */
        u32         udma_frame_count;   /* Nr. of items in udma_frames */
        struct udma_frame
                    *udma_frames;       /* DMA descriptors per frame */
        u32         udma_desc_count;    /* Total nr. of DMA descriptors */
        ...
};
```

Questions:

1. How to properly pin user buffer pages and mark them as not movable?
2. If one frame ends and next frame starts in the same page, is it correct to handle it as two independent pages, i.e. pin the page twice?
3. The data comes from device to user buffer and app is supposed to not write to its buffer, but I have no control over it. Can I use `DMA_FROM_DEVICE` or rather 
   use `DMA_BIDIRECTIONAL` just in case?
4. Do I need to use something like `SetPageReserved`/`ClearPageReserved` or `mark_page_reserved`/`free_reserved_page`?
5. Is IOMMU/swiotlb somehow involved? E.g. i915 driver doesn't use `sg_alloc_table_from_pages` if swiotlb is active?
6. What the difference between `set_page_dirty`, `set_page_dirty_lock` and `SetPageDirty` functions?

Thanks for any hint.

PS: I cannot change the way the application gets the data without breaking our library API maintained for many years. So please do not advise e.g. to `mmap` kernel buffer...

Comment: do you have mechanism to release used page frames as you process through your circular buffer. second point when those errors start after wrap circ. buff?

Comment: The user buffer is pinned on acquisition start (one IOCTL) and stays pinned for whole acquisition until the application stops it (another IOCTL). Applications copies frames out from that buffer for further processing based on a notifications (another side channel using `poll` and IOCTLs). Depends on circular buffer size but it usually wraps every few seconds. The error occurs after hours (shortest test was ~6h, longest about 40 hours so far).

Comment: The try_to_free_pages() function is called directly by the allocating process/task when there is a serious problem with available free memory pages. This happens in heavy system load when the kswapd thread cannot keep pace with the process that are hungry for pages. These processes keep requesting for more and more pages even before the kswapd deamon is able to free some for allocation.  In this situation the allocator itself calls this function to rapidly free up some pages if possible. reference-link : https://linux-mm.org/PageOutKswapd

Comment: That's a part of kernel I don't understand at all. What does it mean for me? How can I block pinned pages to get swapped? BTW, my system doesn't have swap partition and the circ. buffer can be from a few megabytes up to 2GB (theoretically up to 4GB)...

Comment: ... total RAM is 16GB and whole system barely uses a half...

Comment: nobody has a clue?

Comment: `READ == READ` is a curious way of providing a true value for the `write` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you put "READ == READ" as the third paramter? You need put flag there.

`err = get_user_pages_fast(frame->uaddr, nr_pages, READ == READ, pages);`

You need put "FOLL_LONGTERM" here, and FOLL_PIN is set by get_user_pages_fast internally. See https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/pin_user_pages.html#case-2-rdma

In addition, you need take care of cpu and device memory coherence. Just call "dma_sync_sg_for_device(...)" before dma transfer, and "dma_sync_sg_for_cpu(...)" after dma transfer.

Comment: I've solved the problem a while ago exactly as you said.
At a time of writing I worked with kernel 4.4 and 4.15. The prototype of 'get_user_pages_fast' function changed in kernel 5.2 to use 'gup_flags' instead of 'int write' flag.

Comment: Is the problem solved by adding FOLL_LONGTERM, or the coherence sync calls before and after DMA transfer, or both?